# Bootstrap Text Align Center Vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a text vertically center on 100vh height.
Here is what I've done

```css
.about-header {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
}
.about-header p {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid about-header text-center">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @chirag try to give some answer rather than only editing from months with same format.  (off topic)

Comment: Go ahead and Google how to vertically center in CSS.

Comment: @PraveenPuglia, My ques was about vertically center. How it became as duplicate. Who told you to ans like this `Go ahead and Google how to vertically center in CSS`. If you can not ans just leave it. I ask here after searching google. I faced problem thats why ask here.

Comment: ya i will do that..@leo the lion

Comment: @nikolas - My bad! while flagging I selected the wrong question that was duplicate. If you see the *Linked* section on the right sidebar of this page, you'll see a lot of questions where something needs to be vertically center aligned. Also, it's been answered on SO for how many times I can't count. Writing answer to the same question is really the thing any community should avoid.

Comment: @nikolas in fact, if you google **vertical center css** you get [this](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) as the first result which pretty much has everything you can do to center something in almost all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this below CSS:-

```
.about-header{
    height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
       -ms-flex-pack: center;
     justify-content: center;
   -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
         align-items: center;
}
```

Your content will be vertically aligned.

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Is it supports all browser incl. old

Comment: Yes, I've added all the browser auto prefixes. Because there is a problem with the Flex.

Comment: You mentioned in your answer that this will work without explaining what's the real problem and why it works. Consider adding that too!